# Add drop down menu on tab label

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I'm interested how I can add drop down menu with options when I right click on tab label with the mouse? Are there any examples?

Comment: is JComboBox what you want?

Comment: I want standard right click menu https://www.google.bg/search?q=right+click+menu&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=mJ6sUaeMBMKuPM-qgPAF&biw=1280&bih=635&sei=mp6sUYblH4W9OYjpgfAI

Comment: I got confused with the word drop-down-menu, it's called contex-menu

Comment: @pinkpanther JComboBox would be wrong anyway - that's a swing component, not a JavaFX based one.

Comment: @berry120 sorry I'm not into javafx, I don't know about it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`setContextMenu()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setContextMenu%28javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu%29) on Tab to do this. The [ContextMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html) javadoc page has information on creating the menu - it's very similar to a standard JavaFX menu (just do `contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2);`, etc.